# Python __str__ method return values of a list of objects in multiple lines

Tags: python, string, return

I am just wondering if there is a better way to return the str() result of the objects in multiple lines

say i have a list of objects like below:

```
books = [object1, object2, object3....]
```

and I would like to return the result in multiple lines ....

such as:

```
String result of object 1...
String result of object 2...
String result of object 3...
```

I managed to have this done by forming a string concatenation but I don't think this is a good method

```
        result_string = ""
        for item in self.__books:
            result_string += ("{}({}),ISBN:{},${:.2f}".format(item.title,item.author,item.isbn,item.price) + "\n")
        return  result_string[:-1]
```

Can anyone please share a better solution? thanks in advance

Comment: `"\n".join(my_list)`?

Comment: maybe you should set the `__repr__` method of your object?